# Values to configure pagination rules in Rest API connector in azure data factory to get data and load into sql database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Need values to configure in Rest API connector in Azure data factory recently getting only 1000 records. Need how to setup configuration so that the values can be looped.(Pagination rules to configure continuous token).

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I am trying to find what I need to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68186437/pagination-rules-value-in-azure-data-factory-v2-for-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support),ADF pagination rules only support below patterns.

[image]

I think you could adopt the pattern: `Next request’s query parameter = property value in current response body` to set the page size, then pass it into next request as parameter.

As mentioned in the rules, the connector will stop iterating when it gets HTTP status code 204 (No Content), or any of the JSONPath expression in "paginationRules" returns null.

Comment: unable to set the properties for pagination rules (what all  we need to configure to loop the data)