# Pagination rules' Value in Azure Data Factory V2 (for Rest API)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to fill in **Value** box inside Pagination rules explained on [this article](https://sqlkover.com/azure-data-factory-and-the-exact-online-rest-api-dealing-with-pagination/) which was published recently (in May 25th 2021).

[image]

My Request URL is [this one](https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=%5BSELECT%20%2A%20FROM%203497679f-5984-584e-a7cd-2f8641e5e0f0%5D%3B):

So, based on my URL's data, I would like to know how to insert all rows (total 15,315 rows) instead of 500 rows.

I am new to Rest API, and I guess I was looking for an indicator that points to the next set of records.

Currently, when I run Azure Data Factory V2 without Pagination rules, it only inserts 500 rows of data into Azure database.

Comment: Your URL returns `{"message":"Could not instantiate the table due to a lack of schema."}`

I can't learn much from this.  You need to tell how the first request looks, and the last response looks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I got from my issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/468561/azure-data-factory-pagination-issue.html#answer-470345